# Can I detect duplicated videos using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, duplicates, md5sum

Is it possible to detect duplicate videos (.mp4 files) using ffmpeg (or similar tools)?

There are around 3000 videos in my file system, some of them twice (since these are automatically downloaded by a bot from various sources). So it can happen that these differ a little from the video / audio quality.

My first idea now would be to render the videos to a quality that is consistent and store the MD5 hash of the file in the database. There I would check for duplicate hashes.

Is this the right approach or does anyone have an idea how I could best implement this?

Comment: I do not think comparing hashes will work. The files will need to be *exactly* the same for the hashes to match. A difference in a single bit will be enough for the hashes to be different.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón do you know a sensible alternative?

Comment: I suppose you have some context information of every video (title, category, source or something) that you can use to reduce the problem. You could read about string similarity and use something like the Levenshtein distance. Another possibility would be comparing video durations: different videos should have different (allowing some slack) durations, right?